# Weather indicator not showing felt air temperature?

Tags: indicator, weather

I installed Weather Indicator for Ubuntu 11.04, but I can't find the information about the felt air temperature (like temperature is 30 degree, feels like 32 degree). How could I get that information? I can get this from old Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that feature is not in the current version of indicator-weather.  [The next major version](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WeatherIndicator/) (foggy) will have it.  For the latest features and bug fixes (including felt air temperatures when they arrive), add our [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~weather-indicator-team/+archive/ppa): ppa:weather-indicator-team/ppa

If you want felt air temperatures *now*, then perhaps you should try [My-Weather-Indicator](https://launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator), another weather indicator.

Disclosure: I'm involved with indicator-weather.

Comment: i very much like indicator-weather and miss that feature too, but also i have to restart it daily due to segmentation faults -- so looking forward to 'foggy' not only for felt air temp. ;)